# Access Facebook user info using bot

Tags: facebook-graph-api, bots, facebook-messenger-bot

The Messenger API only allows bots to access limited user information such as name, profile picture and language. Is there any way to access more information such as birthday, address or friend list? Can I obtain an access token from within the messenger chat?

Comment: I don't believe so. You could send them a link to a page that does the OAuth flow, perhaps.

Comment: @ceejayoz yeah, I am aware of that option, but I would like to avoid redirectingg the user to another page

Comment: Account linking is the only possible way.

Comment: @CBroe account linking as in linking the PSID with a profile that a user created for my application? The thing is, I didn't want to have the user create another account.

Comment: Account linking is just a mechanism to link the user with _any_ other login system. That system doesn’t have to be “external”, it can of course also be the standard Facebook login to your app.